# Refresh Excel Web App workbook

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps

We are using Excel Web App for Sharepoint 2010.

We have customized page so we have added a button in a ascx control to add a row using open XML SDK 2.0. How can we refresh page in order to see the new row added to the Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [EWA.Workbook.recalcAsynch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee589048.aspx) method.  There's a good example of it in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cumgranosalis/archive/2009/11/19/introduction-to-the-excel-services-javascript-om-part-1-humble-beginnings.aspx).

The above example shows using a timeout to set a short delay before the control refreshes.  If you wire this into the click event of your button, the delay might come in handy if you're adding a new row asynchronously.

If you're writing server code, it might provide a better alternative.  I'm less familiar with the Excel Web Access Server APIs.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think Excel Web App doesn't support this methods, as shown in [this comparison](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2010/07/21/excel-services-and-excel-web-apps-common-different-features.aspx). I am newbie to Sharepoint 2010, so I'm not sure if it is possible to use them.